# Multiprocessing for browser in python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, load-testing

I want to hit a website at a very high frequency like 100 hits/sec.

In my code below, i have a sample process to open google.com and find an element and record time and then do some more random operations.

I observed that even for 5 request, **time varies in seconds**.
Ex

```
17:38:04
17:38:05
17:38:05
17:38:05
17:38:06
```

I need 100 requests to show same time. Please improve my code or suggest something else to do so. I am open to use any technology that can help me achieve 100 hits per sec. My application is browser based which need to submit HTML form and calling API in background.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def run_test(params):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("http://google.com")
    a = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
    print time.ctime()
    a.send_keys("priyanka chopra")
    a = driver.find_element_by_name("btnG")
    a.click()
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    count=5
    parameters = range(count)
    pool = mp.Pool(len(parameters))
    pool.map(run_test, parameters)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your motivation behind that?

Comment: What you are trying to do could be mistaken for a DOS attack (or maybe it's supposed to be one?). Are you sure there's no other way to go about this?

Comment: I am checking my APIs. We have implemented API testing via browser. Fill form on page 1 and see result on page 2. So, my motive is basically load testing to make as many hits as possible per minute.

Comment: Have you looked at using a load testing tool like http://locust.io/ rather than rolling your own?

Comment: can we do thing like filling data and submit form in locust. Do you have a link of example please. I read somewhere that locust never stops by its own. I mean, if i need the test to stop after 100 requests. We have to stop locust manually.